# How do I increase from one number to another?

Tags: excel-formula

This is a very basic Excel problem. I have a number that I'm starting with, 1000, in cell B2. The number I'd like to increase to is 135,000, located in B40. How would I go about using a formula to increase from 1000 to 135,000 in a way that would fill the cells in between the two numbers with values that increase proportionately? I'm making a rollout plan where the number of units need to increase proportionately, but where the number of units needs to increase slowly (i.e. not double between cells).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in b3, put

```
=B2+(B$40-B$2)/38
```

with 38 being 40-2. Then, drag that formula down to B39.
See: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SITsLCfSbsP1po6Og6gR3aquQuxUb2iyQrde9sQ2N2M/edit?usp=sharing